How can i repeat row with inputs in a form
How can I repeat row with inputs in a form as ACF repeater?
I need create inputs dynamically clicking on '+' at the end of row. The row of fields will post as array or object. I need it as array ou json on the table. I guess already see some like this with jquery

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
